# SQL query to Copy rows by incrementing ID based on category

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table having two columns

If the category name is same, category id will be same

```
CatID CatName

1       Cat1
1       Cat1
1       Cat1
2       Cat2
2       Cat2
3       Cat3
3       Cat3
3       Cat3
```

I want to copy the above table rows to the same table to get result like below

```
CatID CatName
1       Cat1
1       Cat1
1       Cat1
2       Cat2
2       Cat2
3       Cat3
3       Cat3
3       Cat3
4       Cat1
4       Cat1
4       Cat1
5       Cat2
5       Cat2
6       Cat3
6       Cat3
6       Cat3
```

Where CatID 4 is the top+1 of CATID

I know, i can use the followng query:

```
 insert into [table1]  
 select (SELECT MAX([CatID]) from [table1]) +
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) as [CatID], CatName 
 from [table1]
```

which give result like below, that i dont want.

```
CatID CatName

4       Cat1
5       Cat1
6       Cat1
7       Cat2
8       Cat2
9       Cat3
10      Cat3
11      Cat3
```

Here, CatID is incrementing, i need to increment catid based on category.

Comment: You're table is poorly designed. You should never have multiple fully identical rows in any table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You over complicated your select statement. Try this one:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT CatId + (SELECT MAX(CatId) FROM Table1), CatName
FROM Table1
```

[see fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/68f48/2)

**Note:** I Agree with Amit's comment: this is a poor design.
I can't think of any situation where identical rows should be inserted to any table.